# How many $E_\infty$-ring structures are there on the complex cobordism spectrum?

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

There is a well known $E_\infty$-ring structure on the complex cobordism spectrum $MU$ coming from the fact that $MU$ is a Thom spectrum over the infinite loop space $BU$. Here is my question: Is it known if this the only $E_\infty$-ring structure that can be put on $MU$ (say up to $E_\infty$-equivalence)? If there are more, do we have any understanding of the space of $E_\infty$-ring structures we can put on $MU$?

Comment: A small correction: you need more than $BU$ being an infinite loop space, you also need the map $BU\to BGL_1(\mathbb{S})$ to be an infinite loop map (the latter space is often called $BF$ in the older literature), otherwise any other $E_\infty$-structure on $BU$ would give an example (and there are others).

Comment: Denis, that is not right.  $MU$ was the quintessential primordial example of an $E_{\infty}$ ring spectrum as found in nature, back in 1972 when we first defined $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra.  One does not even need to mention $BU$ explicitly.   The concrete geometrical construction of $MU$ as an $E_{\infty}$ ring spectra can be made in terms of Thom spaces of the tautological bundles over Grassmannians or by use of the two-sided bar construction.  That is in \SI.2 of  http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/e_infty.pdf.  The $E_{\infty}$ structure on $BU$ is not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Also, p-locally, a uniqueness theorem of Adams and Priddy implies that there is a unique $E_{\infty}$ structure on $BU$ such that the $p$th power of the generator of $H_2(BU;\mathbb{F}_p)$ is non-zero. See Theorem1.2 of https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/Adams-Priddy.pdf

Comment: An interesting question and I suspect that this is not known. Knowing the space of $E_\infty$ ring structures would, in particular, tell us the structure of the space of $E_\infty$ self-equivalences of $MU$, and for that we need to know something about the spectrum maps $bu \to gl_1 MU$. I suspect that there are many structures; if I was going to try to build an exotic one, I would try to patch together the ordinary $p$-complete $MU$'s with rational $MU$ in an exotic way using an arithmetic square, in the same way that one constructs exotic loop spaces.

Comment: @TylerLawson, do you have a reference for this construction of exotic loop spaces?

Comment: @CWcx This is a bit late, but check out Zabrodsky mixing. This is what I think Tyler's referring to.